# Array with 10 different random elements with no duplicate

Tags: java, arrays, random

im trying to make an array of 10 different elements with Random(), so basically i have this

```
public static int[] RandomArray (int xArra[]) throws java.io.IOException {
    Random Rand = new Random();
    int nal;

    for (int i = 0; i < xArra.length; i++) {
        nal = Rand.nextInt(11); /*I would like to make this thing work with any 
                                numbers, for example, changing this to 50 or 100.
                                In an array of 10 elements it should be 
                                impossible to have a duplicate because with 
                                11 it just prints from 1 to 10. 
                                Thats why i put 11 here.  */  
        for ( int j = 0; j < xArra.length; j++) {
            if (nal == xArra[j]) {
                nal = Rand.nextInt(11); 
                j=0;                  
            }                           
        }

        xArra[i] = nal;

    }           

    return xArra;

}
```

Basically im storing a random number in nal and I run my array in a second For to check 
this random number with the already given ones, and if its equal to any number given in the array it changes it with random again, and runs the For again checking that the new number isnt duplicated, if its not, I stored in xArra[i].

When i run it 3 times, the results look like this:

First run:
8
1
6
4
3
2
10
8
9
7

Second run:
9
3
8
10
7
1
4
5
9
6

Third run:
3
5
2
3
6
7
1
4
10
9

So, as you can see i almost though i had it but it duplicates just 1 number, no 2 or 3, so basically i just want to make this thing work. I just want to print 10 random numbers with no duplicate, no repeats.

Heres my full code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArraynoR {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        int Array[]= new int [10];
        RandomArray(Array);
        for(int i=0; i<Array.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Array[" + (i + 1) + "]:" + Array[i]);   
        }
    }

    public static int[] RandomArray (int xArra[]) throws java.io.IOException... //up

}
```

Please forgive my bad english, I hope I explained myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set j=-1 when you are resetting for the inner for loop and try it. Then it should work

```
    for ( int j = 0; j < xArra.length; j++) {
        if (nal == xArra[j]) {
             nal = Rand.nextInt(11); 
             j=-1;                  
        }                           
    }
```

At the end of the for loop the loop increments the variable so when you set it to 0, before the next check it becomes 1 due to the internal code of the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing and searching for duplicates, create an `ArrayList` containing the numbers in the range of interest.  Use `Collections.shuffle()` to randomize the values, then select however many you want from the shuffled set. Guaranteed to give no duplicates, and much more efficient than a search/reject approach.

ADDENDUM

Perhaps not the prettiest code, but it works and gives the idea...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ShuffleDemo {

   public static int[] RandomArray(int len) {
      ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(len);
      for(int i = 1; i <= len; ++i) {    // initialize the ArrayList with values 1 to len
         al.add(i);
      }
      Collections.shuffle(al);           // shuffle to random order
      int[] results = new int[len];
      // switching return type to ArrayList could eliminate the following loop
      for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {     // copy to array of ints
         results[i] = al.get(i);         // note: create a subset by reducing
      }                                  // the upper bound for this loop                               
      return results;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(RandomArray(10)));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method nextPermutation of the class org.apache.commons.math3.random.RandomDataGenerator (see help here [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html#nextPermutation(int,%20int))) in Apache Math. This method generate random numbers without repetition.